# Token based authentication - Angular 2 + ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI + C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have created token in Class library using C# and created method for token generation in Web API Controller.
I don't know how to implement that token and create authentication in Angular 2 because I'm new to Angular 2.
If someone has a useful example or link feel free to put it in comments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic flow is this:

1. User enters valid credentials to auth server (could be even facebook or google)
2. Server returns some token with an expiry date and info (e.g. userid, scopes, etc.)
3. Client makes requests to your api/server with that token usually in the header
4. Your application validates the token is valid, i.e. not expired, or you can also make a call to the issuing server to make sure it's valid and get more info about the user
5. If it's valid proceed with the flow, else force user to log in again, going back to step 1.

As you can see most of the logic is actually on the server, not sure what is the issue with the angularjs. May be you can have logic in the angularjs routing that anytime the server returns 403 you re-route to login page.

Comment: I understand these five steps but I don't know how to convert all that to Angular 2 code. I have searched for examples but I haven't found one that uses token that is generated by calling method from Web API controller.

Comment: your angular code should save the token coming from the server after authentication locally, add it to header for any calls that require authenticated user, handle any 403 for those calls to redirect to login page.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the advice. Your answer has been accepted :)